# Let A be a set and let R be a reflexive relation on A. Prove that for every positive integer n, R^n is reflexive.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Not sure how I do that,

Let $R$ be a symmetric relation on set $A$.

Proof by induction:

Basis Step: $R^1 = R$ is symmetric is true.

Inductive Step: Assume that $R^n$ is symmetric. To prove: $R^n+1$ is symmetric.
$R^n+1$ is symmetric if for all $(x,y) \in R^{n+1}$, we have $(y,x) \in R^{n+1}$ as well. Assume that $(x,y) \in R^{n+1}$.
Now, $R^{n+1} = R^n \circ R = R \circ R^n$.

We know that if (x,y) ∈ $R\circ R^n$, then by the definition of composition there exists a $z\in A$ such that $xRz$ and $zR^ny$ i.e $(x,z) \in R$ and $(z,y) \in R^n$.
And we also know that $R$ and $R^n$ are symmetric, which implies that $(z,x)\in R$ and also $(y,z)\in R^n$. Therefore, by definition of composition, $(y,x)\in R\circ R^n$; i.e.; $(y,x)\in R^{n+1}$.

Hence Proved.

is it the same for reflexive stuff?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. You should familiarize yourself with [Markdown and MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to make your questions nicer to read. In particular, you need to line-breaks in your source to produce a new paragraph and you can’t use ascii formatting. I changed the first half for you – you can do the rest. Showing that $R^n$ is reflexive if $R$ is should actually be a bit easier than showing that it is symmetric from the symmetry of $R$.

Comment: There's a little bug in your symmetric-case proof. You show that there's $z$ such that $(y,z)\in R^n$ and $(z,x)\in R$, thus **$(y,x)\in R^n\circ R$**. Do you know that $R^n\circ R = R\circ R^n$? If not, this needs proving (by induction). It's not hard: in fact $R^{i+j} = R^iR^j$ for all $i,j\ge 1$, because composition is associative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's similar for reflexive, but easier.

$R^1 = R$ is reflexive, by definition.

Assuming that $R^n$ is reflexive and $x$ in its domain (= domain of $R$), we have

- $(x,x)\in R$, and
- by induction hypothesis $(x,x)\in R^n$.

Hence there is some $y$ (namely, $x$) such that $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,x)\in R^n$; so $(x,x)\in R^{n+1}$.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking how would I word the entire proof when we need to prove R^n+1 is reflexive? Sorry new to relations

Comment: I revised the answer to show the whole proof.